# Paste into notepad cell content from excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a bit of help with creating a batch file and pasteing a certain range from excel into it BUT keeping the text as it is displayed in excel.

**Exemple**: (this is the content of a cell I want to paste into a batch file)

```
"pushd N:\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 102501N - 105000N\
for /f ""delims="" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find ""104020""') do (
cd ..
xcopy ""%%a"" ""C:\Users\agrigoriu\Desktop\COPIERE\"" /E /D /Y )
@ECHO ---"
```

**Problem 1:** **all the content will be displayed in one single line like this**:
pushd N:\contracte\CONTRACTE NEVOI PERSONALE\Contracte nevoi personale 102501N - 105000N\ for /f ""delims="" %%a in ('dir /b /s ^| find ""104020""') do ( cd .. xcopy ""%%a"" ""C:\Users\agrigoriu\Desktop\COPIERE\"" /E /D /Y ) @ECHO ---"

**Problem 2: it doubles every comma there is in the original text**

this is the code I have so far and it only pastes the information from the range into a notepad (with the problems stated above):

```
Sub test()
    'The range that contains the values
    Range("D:D").Copy
    'Start Notepad And let it recieve focus
    Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
    'Send the keys CTRL+V To Notepad (i.e the window that has focus)
    SendKeys "^V"
End Sub
```

Ideea: One "solution" woud be to paste it first into Word and then copy it again and paste it into notepad but this must work with all standard computers and I observed that not that many have the Word app on vba turned on by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to write the text to a file then open that file in Notepad, that way you have control of formatting and you don't trash whatever the user may have in their clipboard.

```
Dim hF As Integer:  hF = FreeFile()
'// get temp file name
Dim path As String: path = Environ$("TEMP") & "\DUMP.TXT"

Open path For Output As #hF
    Print #hF, Replace$(Range("D1").Text, vbLf, vbCrLf)
Close #hF

Shell "NOTEPAD.EXE " & path, vbNormalFocus
```

(This replaces \n new lines that exist within the cell with \r\n which is the cause of everything appearing on one line)

Comment: Thank you but I get error 55 : File already open. (i don't get it, what file is already open ?!). I made a notepad with dump.txt...

Comment: Close whatever has that file open, the code creates it automatically.

Comment: I don't see anything opened (looked also into processes list to end task it).

Comment: I don't seem to make it copy the whole range (D2:D), says "Range of object method failed". Is there a way to make it copy all D :D  ?

Comment: From D1 downwards are do all the cells have text or are there gaps?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Alex K answer, this works with a range:

```
  Sub test()

Dim hF As Integer:  hF = FreeFile()
Dim output As String

'// get temp file name
Dim path As String: path = Environ$("TEMP") & "\DUMP.TXT"
  Range("D2:D2000").Select
Open path For Output As #hF
    For Each c In Selection
       Print #hF, Replace(c.Value, vbLf, vbCrLf)
        Next c
Close #hF

Shell "NOTEPAD.EXE " & path, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```